# Combining two StateFlows into one stream

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am currently trying to combine two streams and use that result to display into a Compose view in Android. I currently initialize it like this:

```
private var flowA: MutableStateFlow<String?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
private var flowB: MutableStateFlow<String?> = MutableStateFlow(null)

var combinedFlows: Flow<Pair<String?, String?>> =
    flowA.combine(flowB) {a, b ->
        Pair(a, b)
    }
```

Emit like so:

```
// Some logic to create string
flowA.emit("New String") 

// More logic to create another string
flowB.emit("Another New String")
```

In the compose view I am collecting like this:

```
var pairStrings = viewModel.pairStrings.collectAsState()
```

The combined stream is never emiting any data when I emit from `flowA` and `flowB`. Is there something I am missing here?

--Edit--

This is in the view model:

```
val pairStrings: StateFlow<Pair<String?, String?>> = combinedFlows
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        initialValue = Pair(null,null),
        started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
    )
```

Comment: Can you share your Compose logic?

Comment: There isn't much except retrieving the data with `.collectAsState()` and just using the value on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much information, but you need to run/subscribe to the combined flow. I think you need to do the following:

```kotlin
val combinedFlows = flowA.combine(flowB) { a, b ->
    a to b // will emit a Pair with the latest value of flowA and flowB
}.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())
```

The `shareIn` operator runs the upstream flow in a separate coroutine. Doing this, you'll be able to consume the flow.
You need to pass a `CoroutineScope`, assuming you're doing this call in a ViewModel (which should be the best place), you can use the `viewModelScope`. You also need to pass the `SharingState` which will determine the strategy that controls when sharing is started and stopped. In this case, I'm using `WhileSubscribed` which immediately stops the flow when the last subscriber disappears.

Comment: I added the snippet where I declare the pairStrings in the viewmodel. Will `.stateIn` not work for this?

Comment: I don’t think this is necessary. `collectAsState` internally collects the flow in a coroutine.

Comment: Probably there is no need use shareIn operator since the combined state flows will remain active (hot flows).